# Querystring to return a case sensitive string

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

```
string checkUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower();
Uri AbsoluteUri = new Uri(checkUrl);
```

checkUrl = https://domain.co.il/HtmlPage.aspx?l=https://domain.co.il/uploads/Untitled-4-1024x377.png

I heve:
https://domain.co.il/uploads/**U**ntitled-4-1024x377.png  -- U UPPER

and after ask Querystring:

```
string L = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(AbsoluteUri.Query).Get("L");
```

L = https://domain.co.il/uploads/**u**ntitled-4-1024x377.png   -- u lower

How can I get the parameter as it is?

Comment: What parameter do you expect here? What value do you expect to be in `L`? Your URL doesn't even have a query string, note that (assuming `AbsoluteUri` is a `Uri`) `AbsoluteUri.Query` returns an empty string.

Comment: Why are you doing `ToLower` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

**checkUrl** cannot contain uppercase characters, because you are calling the **ToLower()** method.
If you want the **result** in the **original** case, reconsider the use of the ToLower() method